# No me toma en cuenta el IF - else al realizar la prueba

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Tengo este código y no se que estoy haciendo mal que no me lo toma con la lógica que pienso que está hecho.

¿Qué debe hacer?: Si se muestra un anuncio (AvisoTxt) que dice que no se puede usar el elemento anterior (RegInst0) entonces cierre el anuncio y haga clic en el siguiente elemento (RegInst1). Y si no se muestra entonces siga su curso.

```
protected by AvisoTxt = By.XPath ("// * [@ id = 'xxxx']");

Driver.FindElement (RegInst0) .Click ();

if (Driver.FindElement (AvisoTxt) .Displayed)

        {
            Driver.FindElement(AvisoTxt).Click();

            Driver.FindElement(CloseBtn).Click();

            Driver.FindElement(RegInst1).Click();                
         }
        else 
        {
        wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(InstructBtn).Displayed);
        Driver.FindElement(InstIncBtn).Click();
        }
```

Al correr la prueba me arroja este error.

> Mensaje: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no existe ese
> elemento: No se puede ubicar el elemento: {"método": "xpath",
> "selector": "// * [@ id = 'xxxx']"}

*Aclaro que el problema es que cuando no aparece el Marco debe seguir su curso y lo que hace es esperar el marco y arroja el error. Ya invertí el if-else sugerido por el debug, le puse timer, y ya no se cuantas cosas mas he probado.*

Comment: Una pregunta, las lineas `Driver.FindElement (RegInst0) .Click ();` estas contatenando o `.Display` es parte de la clase? tambien se repite en `Driver.FindElement (AvisoTxt) .Displayed` el .Display esta separado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a los que comentaron.
Solventé cambiando el if-else por un try-catch. El problema no era que no me tomaba el frame nuevo, sino que cuando el frame nuevo no aparecía, el sistema debía seguir su camino y no lo hacía sino que esperaba el frame. Lo cierto es que en otro foro me explicaron que el condicional IF me servirá para eventos dentro de un mismo frame, y con el Try puede usarse para fuera del mismo frame. Me funcionó perfecto de esa manera.

Answer (score 0):

Puede que el elemento tarde en aparecer o cambie su id cada vez, puedes probar a esperar la aparicion del elemento:

```
protected by AvisoTxt = By.XPath ("// * [@ id = 'xxxx']");
Driver.FindElement (RegInst0) .Click ();
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeOut)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(AvisoTxt));
if (Driver.FindElement (AvisoTxt) .Displayed){
  ...
```